# @contextconfiguration analog for annotation style

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

If I have xml configuration file I write so:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "testContext.xml")
```

But what I must to write If I mark my beans by annotations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@ContextConfiguration` has an attribute called `classes` of type `Class<?>[]` in which you can specify `@Configuration` classes to be loaded.

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {com.company.MyConfiguration.class})
```

where `MyConfiguration` is, for example,

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public MyBean myBean() {
        return new MyBean();
    } 
}
```